# Why does SQL Server 2017 asks for login for every query window

Tags: sql-server-2017

I am a new user configured on SQL Server 2017 for existing database server. Every time I try to execute in new query window, it asks my login. "Remember password" doesn't help either.

The option "Disconnect after query executes" under Tools->Options->query execution->advanced is unchecked.

This is so annoying and doesn't allow me to work in multiple query windows. Any suggestions to get around this are appreciated.